# Small, portable web browser library?

Tags: c++, html, browser

I am looking for a small and portable web browser to embed into my 3D engine. Basically, I need something small and fast that can render into a graphical buffer and take my input for links and stuff. It would be great if it could do JS as well.

So far I've looked at Gecko and Webkit and Webkit is the winner so far (Gecko is way too huge and messy to even consider).

Are there other more obscure engines that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [HTMLayout](http://www.terrainformatica.com/htmlayout/).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is an option: http://princeofcode.com/awesomium.php

From the website:

Awesomium is a library that makes it easy for developers to embed the web in their applications. For example, it can be used for:

- Powering an in-game GUI using
- HTML/JS/CSS Rendering a live web-page to a 3D object and interacting with it
- A framework for an advanced, 3D web-browser
- An offscreen renderer for snapshots or recordings of web-pages
- The implementation of in-game advertising. and more!

Comment: Awesomium is based on Webkit from what I understand.

Comment: Yes Awesomium is based on webkit.

Comment: +1 for WebKit implementations; take a look at Chromium, too (which is available also for commercial use afaik)